# How to segment mp4 with ffmpeg or avconv, fast, where times are specified?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avconv

I need to segment mp4 in specified pieces. They are all different durations. Example segmentation:

```
1 - 0:00:00 to 0:01:11
segment 2 - 0:01:11 to 0:04:24
segment 3 - 0:05:51 to 0:06:30
...
```

I already wrote a script extracting them one by one, but it is pretty slow.
I guess because it wastes a lot of time opening the file, decoding and seeking from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffmpeg has the option

```
- segment_times times 
  Specify a list of split points. times contains
  a list of comma separated duration specifications,
  in increasing order. See also the segment_time option.
```